# Create child object from within model

Tags: symfony

I'm currently refactoring a part of my code and was wondering if it is considered good practice to create a new child object within an entity's class.

E.g. I currently have an entity 'Tournament' and a controller for this tournament. If I would go to /tournament/{id}/start, the tournament would start. Currently, I create all the rounds for the tournament in my controller, but I'm trying to move away form a fat controller to a fat model.

Is it good practice to have this function in my Tournament model?

```
    public function start() {

        for ($x; $x <= $this->amountOfRounds; $x++) {
            $newRound = new Round($this, $x);
            $this->addRound($newRound);
        }

    }
```

(NOTE: quite untested code in this block, but you get the point)

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Contrary to what @VBee has indicated, your approach is fine.  Keep in mind that "best practice" is a fantasy.  It all comes down to opinion.

Comment: @Cerad, you right, @ Neglexis you ask for a best practice, I gave mine, but it's not the only one. I will edit my post

Comment: @Cerad Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @VBee I wasn't really looking for the 'best' practice, just wanted to know if my way was seen as 'bad' practice. I'm currently just building an MVP and we'll probably switch over to another language in the future :

Answer (score 1):

An approach I suggest you is to have a Manager to do business process:

```
class TournamentManager
{
    public function start(TournamentInterface $tournament)
    {
        $tournament->addRound(new Round());
    }
}

interface TournamentInterface
{
    function addRound(RoundInterface $round);
}
```

And use interfaces as much as possible.

Comment: This is the first time I see Managers and/or Interfaces being mentioned, so I have no idea where to start. I have no clue what their general function is, as it's never mentioned in the Symfony book..

Comment: It's a PHP best practice. You should learn to use PHP before symfony. http://www.phptherightway.com/#programming_paradigms

Comment: A manager is simply a class that do the business stuff, such as start a Tournament. Manager is an standart but you can use whatever you want. I simply suggest you to keep your business logic away from you model layer.

Comment: So that's simply a way to keep your model skinny too, right?

Comment: Yes but it's not the first aim of the Manager.

Comment: @VBee - got anything to back up the notion that your approach is a "best practice"?

Comment: @Cerad, I always try to follow the single responsibility principle. With a good nomenclature, that gave me a sufficient readability in my projects.

Comment: @VBee, Nice thing about patterns and standards in general is that there are so many to chose from.  The Domain Driven Design people tend to avoid Anemic Domain Models.  But it really comes down to whatever works for a given application.